# How to send object parameter in Retrofit GET request?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2, android-networking

I have a back-end server that works like this

```
"api/videos?search_object={"cat_id" :2, "channel_id" : 3, etc}
```

Basily you can give a search object as input and it will filter the list base on that object. Now I want to use this service with Retrofit with something like this

```
@GET("videos")
Call<VideoListResponse> listVideos(@Query("search_object") VideoSearchObject videoSearchObject);
```

But the above code doesn't work, I can first convert VideoSearchModel to JSON string that pass it to retrofit like this

```
@GET("videos")
Call<VideoListResponse> listVideos(@Query("search_object") String jsonString);
```

I wonder if there is a better more clear way? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I am afraid that is the only way if you want to send json string in query.

Answer (score 8):

Retrofit 2 supports it. All you have to do is implementing a custom converter factory with the `stringConverter()` method overridden.

Consider the following Retrofit-friendly interface with a custom annotation:

```java
@Target(PARAMETER)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@interface ToJson {
}
```

```java
interface IService {

    @GET("api/videos")
    Call<Void> get(
            @ToJson @Query("X") Map<String, Object> request
    );

}
```

The annotation is used to denote an argument that must be converted to a string.

Mock `OkHttpClient` to always respond with "HTTP 200 OK" and dump request URLs:

```java
private static final OkHttpClient mockHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(chain -> {
            System.out.println(chain.request().url());
            return new Response.Builder()
                    .request(chain.request())
                    .protocol(HTTP_1_0)
                    .code(HTTP_OK)
                    .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), "OK"))
                    .build();
        })
        .build();
```

```java
private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
```

```java
private static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(mockHttpClient)
        .baseUrl("http://whatever")
        .addConverterFactory(new Converter.Factory() {
            @Override
            public Converter<?, String> stringConverter(final Type type, final Annotation[] annotations, final Retrofit retrofit) {
                if ( !hasToJson(annotations) ) {
                    return super.stringConverter(type, annotations, retrofit);
                }
                return value -> gson.toJson(value, type);
            }

            private boolean hasToJson(final Annotation[] annotations) {
                for ( final Annotation annotation : annotations ) {
                    if ( annotation instanceof ToJson ) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        })
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();
```

To test it you can simply invoke the service interface method:

```
final IService service = retrofit.create(IService.class);
service.get(ImmutableMap.of("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2")).execute();
```

Result:

> http://whatever/api/videos?X={%22k1%22:%22v1%22,%22k2%22:%22v2%22}

Where the `X` parameter argument is an encoded representation of `{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code, it works for me

```
@GET("api")
Call<Response> method(@Query("") JSONObject param);

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key", "value");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> "api/videos?search_object={"cat_id" :2, "channel_id" : 3, etc}
> ```
>
> Basically you can give a search object as input

No, you do not give an object as input. You provide multiple parameters enclosed in `{ }` so that it *looks* like an object (a JavaScript object that is, not a Java object). In reality it is just a string.

The constructed url is just a bunch of characters. There is no such thing as an "object" in an url.

Keep doing it like `@Query("search_object") String jsonString`. Although you might also want to rename the parameter from `jsonString` to `searchString`, since that is what it is. It is not a JSON string. A JSON string would have all `"` characters escaped like `\"`.